# Aurelia custom rule validation that depends two date pickers

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have two date pickers say startDate and endDate. My requirement is needed to validate these fields when picks one date. When selected a date range checking is done whether it has active subscription on selected range. If no both date pickers should be shown "no active subscription..." message. Once the active date range selected, both messages should be removed. I goes through aurelia validation customRules. But i didnt resolvethe issue.

Here is the code part:

```
ValidationRules
   .ensure('startDate').required().satisfiesRule('validateSubscription', 'expiryDate').withMessage("")
   .ensure('expiryDate').required().satisfiesRule('validateSubscription', 'startDate').withMessage("")
   .on(PublishQuestionPaper);
```

The custom rule is :

```
 ValidationRules.customRule('validateSubscription',
   (value, obj, otherPropertyName) => {
     return value === null || 
            value === undefined || 
            value === ''|| 
            this.getValidLicenseForQPPublish(value) === true &&                 
            this.getValidLicenseForQPPublish(otherPropertyName) === true;
   },
   'Custom validation rule',
   otherPropertyName => ({ otherPropertyName }));
```

The function getValidLicenseForQPPublish() has lines of code that checks backend for available subscription and return true if available else returns false

Comment: Show us some code, and someone might be able to solve any specific issues you're having. Simply saying "I want to do this, but I tried and it didn't work" isn't much use to us.

Comment: You don't need to check whether a value is empty - that's the job of `required()`.